# how can I import dwg file in ursina python?

Tags: python, 3d, autocad, ursina

I want to create a background for my game with autocad, but I don't know to set the dwg project as background in my python (using ursina) app. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

.dwg files are not supported by ursina. You'll have to first export it to a supported one like .obj, .glb or .gltf and then import that.